# use basic auth over an https connection for phpmyadmin

Tags: apache-http-server, mysql

I'm having issues with my server that was recently investigated by a website scanning tool. The result as follow.

> **Impact:** User credentials are sent as cleartext and are vulnerable to packet sniffing.
>
> **Recommendation:** Use Basic Authentication over an HTTPS connection.
>
> **affected items:** /phpmyadmin/setup

From what I understand, it wants me to change the authentication of `/phpmyadmin/setup` from basic HTTP to HTTPS.

How can I change http auth into https auth for this url?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  You need to change the URL to an HTTPS URL - this entails getting and using an HTTPS server - if you run your apache server (and control your firewalling) you can purchase an SSL cert and set up Apache to run as both an HTTP and HTTPS server, otherwise you will need to speak to your service provider.

The mechanics of changing an HTTP url to an HTTPS url is as theoretically as simple as modifying the form tag, but in practice you will want to migrate the calling page to https as well - which may land up meaning moving the entire application to HTTPS depending on how its written.

Although probably not as good as HTTPS, you can make the site more secure by changing from Basic Authentication to [Digest authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication), which at least encrypts the password before sending it.   Its not impregnable, but its a lot better.  This might be "Good Enough" depending on your application, and is a lot easier then setting up a secure server.

Comment: would it be easier or practical if i just remove the directory `/phpmyadmin/setup` instead? so it wont show up on the next scanning?

Comment: If that directory is not used and its the only place where basic authentication is used, yes, deleting it will fix your problem.  You might want to rename it to (some_random_string)_setup just in case it turns out to be neccessary and you want to rename it back.

Comment: i manage to get inside my `/phpmyadmin/setup` and some notification to change the access to `HTTPS`. upon clicking the link, it redirects me to `https://.../phpmyadmin/setup` which is BLANK. i looked around the page and there's a radio button to`Force secured connection while using phpMyAdmin` i clicked on it and restarted apache. but still getting a blank https:../phpmyadmin/setup page. does this have to do with my actual server OS? im using ubuntu atm.

Comment: It most likely has to do with the web server configuration.